# Phonegap build - ref = window.open(encodeURI(url),'_blank','location=no'); is displaying the DONE button!?

Tags: phonegap-build, inappbrowser

With the phonegap build.
Im using

```
ref = window.open(encodeURI(url),'_blank','location=no');
```

to open the InAppBrowser and with location=no it should ́nt display the DONE button in the toolbar!

Comment: pretty sure the way that it is working is correct.  Setting `'location=no'` is the location bar not the bottom toolbar

Comment: Hi whodeee, and thanks, yes you are right, location=no means that the addressbar is not displayed, there is no way off hiding the toolbar with the done button and with _blank, you have to use _self if you don´t want the toolbar, but then the webpage is not zoomed right, it is only displaying the top left corner of the webpage. Not the way I would have programed the inappbrowser...

Answer (score 0):

It might be a whitelist issue. Make sure that the webpage you are trying to load is not configured on the config.xml whitelist.